# Coupling heatsink RC network to MOSFET's Cauer circuit

Tags: mosfet, power-electronics, semiconductors, thermal, igbt

I am trying to understand simple RC thermal simulation to analyse the temperature rise in  Rohm a 1200 V N-channel SiC MOSFET SCT3040KR.

RC Cauer parameters are as depicted in the LTspice circuit bellow. My issue rise when adding external RC network of the heatsink. The simulation gives exactly same Tj rise curve with and without the additional external RC components.

(values used were in Rohm application note)

1 - Why is the simulation ignoring the additional RC? I have read in an Infineon note that it's not very effective to just couple more RC nodes to the component measured network, as they don't have same time constant, but I am not really getting this? Aren't Rth/Cth of the semiconductor directly related to the physical structure? Or am I missing another point?

[image]

Temperature with external heatsink :
[image]

Temperature without external heatsink:

[image]

Comment: The RC timeconstant of C4 and R5 is huge compared to the rest - What if you simulate for a longer timeperiod?

Comment: i tried to simulate for longer termperiod and there's a minor difference between the two curves. i found all the RC data in rohm application note; and i have no idea if they reflect a real system or no